# Automation of a task on third party software

Tags: automation

I am working with a third party software. I don't have access to the code. I do repetitive task with this software that needs humain interaction. I want to automate those task using Delphi, c++ for example. This would involve copy/paste of text from third party software to Delphi or copying/pasting screenshots of the third party software to Delphi, c++ for image processing. 
Do you know of any way I could achieve that? I saw some website like winautomation.

Comment: If you explain better - maybe people will help with better answers.

Comment: Thanks ekostadinov for the unconstructive comment. I rephrased following your input